# Scala Adapter pattern - autommagically allow "duck typing" for classes with same methods

Tags: scala, mocking, adapter, duck-typing

Let's say class `A` is being used in some code, and that I want to use instead class `B`, which has exactly the same methods as class `A` - without having `B` extend `A`. What would be the easiest way to go about this? In other words, I'm looking for simple ready-to-use  and ***generic*** implementation of `adaptBtoA` (it should work for any two classes that have the same structure/methods).

```scala
class A {
  def foo(x: String) = "A_" + x
}

class B {
  def foo(x: String) = "B_" + x
}

def bar(a: A) = {
  // ...
}

bar(adaptBtoA(new B()))
```

If you're familiar with duck typing interfaces of Go, that's sort of the semantics I'm aiming for.

---

***EDIT***

I think a generalized solution might be impossible due to type erasure, although I'm not sure. Here's my attempt using the `mockito` library:

```scala
def adapt[F, T](impl: F): T = mock[T](new Answer[Any]() {
  override def answer(inv: InvocationOnMock): Any =
    classOf[T]
      .getDeclaredMethod(inv.getMethod.getName, inv.getMethod.getParameterTypes:_*)
      .invoke(impl, inv.getArguments:_*)
})

val a: A = adapt[B, A](new B()) 
val res = a.foo("test") // should be "B_test" but errors in compilation
```

unfortunately this does not work as I get the following compiler error:

```
type arguments [T] conform to the bounds of none of the overloaded alternatives of
value mock: [T <: AnyRef](name: String)(implicit classTag: scala.reflect.ClassTag[T])T <and> [T <: AnyRef](mockSettings: org.mockito.MockSettings)(implicit classTag: scala.reflect.ClassTag[T])T <and> [T <: AnyRef](defaultAnswer: org.mockito.stubbing.Answer[_])(implicit classTag: scala.reflect.ClassTag[T])T <and> [T <: AnyRef](implicit classTag: scala.reflect.ClassTag[T])T
```

I can, however, use hardcoded types for specific use-cases:

```scala
def adaptBtoA(b: B): A = mock[A](new Answer[Any]() {
  override def answer(inv: InvocationOnMock): Any =
    classOf[B]
      .getDeclaredMethod(inv.getMethod.getName, inv.getMethod.getParameterTypes:_*)
      .invoke(b, inv.getArguments:_*)
})

val a: A = adaptBtoA(new B()) 
val res = a.foo("test")  // res == "B_test"
```

If getting class type information from template parameter at runtime is impossible, perhaps I can use macros to generate all of the `adapt` functions I need at compile time? Then the code will look something like:

```scala
genAdapt[B, A]()
genAdapt[D, C]()
// etc...
```

But I don't know enough about scala macros yet to implement this, or if this is possible.

Comment: In Scala you can use **structural typing** which will work like _duck typing_. However, a **typeclass** approach is usually preferable. [here](https://gist.github.com/BalmungSan/c19557030181c0dc36533f3de7d7abf4) you can find a discussion about that _(disclaimer I am the author)_.

Comment: And what about **typeclasses**? I would require quite a bit of refactoring but is the best solution to this problem.

Comment: Other option, would be to provide an **implicit conversion** from `A` to `B` or use the [**magnet pattern**](https://www.clianz.com/2016/04/26/scala-magnet-pattern/) But, IMHO, the best is a **typeclass** implicit conversions are very fragile.

Comment: a **generic** implementation of structurally equivalent type conversions could be serialization and deserialisation, if the classes are properly serializable. throw in and implicit conversion and you would end up with the feature you require.

Comment: @solyd I think you do not get the idea of **typeclasses**, you would only create one _(which defines the common functionality)_. And you would implement it for both `A` & `B` then, you would write your function in terms of the typeclass instead of some concrete type.

Comment: btw: you did you consider structural typing? eg. `type Closable = { def close(): Unit }`. now your code could accept this type and you can supply both structurally equivalent types (A and B).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just missed a few things in your attempt at the `adapt` method. The compiler says: it needs `T` to extends `AnyRef`, and a `ClassTag[T]`. You'd also need a `ClassTag[F]` since you'd invoke the method on `F`, not `T`.

```
def adapt[F: ClassTag, T <: AnyRef : ClassTag](impl: F): T = {
  mock[T](new Answer[Any]() {
    override def answer(inv: InvocationOnMock): Any =
      implicitly[ClassTag[F]].runtimeClass
        .getDeclaredMethod(inv.getMethod.getName, inv.getMethod.getParameterTypes: _*)
        .invoke(impl, inv.getArguments: _*)
  })
}

adapt[B, A](new B()).foo("test") // "B_test"
adapt[A, B](new A()).foo("test") // "A_test"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the proposed **typeclass** solution.

```
trait Foo[T] {
  def foo(t: T)(x: String): String
}

object Foo {
  object syntax {
    implicit class FooOps[T](private val t: T) extends AnyVal {
      @inline
      final def foo(x: String)(implicit ev: Foo[T]): String =
        ev.foo(t)(x)
    }
  }
}

final class A {
  def foo(x: String) = s"A_${x}"
}

object A {
  implicit final val AFoo: Foo[A] =
    new Foo[A] {
      override def foo(a: A)(x: String): String =
        a.foo(x)
    }
}

final class B {
  def foo(x: String) = s"B_${x}"
}

object B {
  implicit final val BFoo: Foo[B] =
    new Foo[B] {
      override def foo(b: B)(x: String): String =
        b.foo(x)
    }
}

def bar[T : Foo](t: T): String = {
  import Foo.syntax._
  t.foo("test")
}
```

Which you can use like this:

```
bar(new A()) 
// res: String = "A_test"

bar(new B()) 
// res: String = "B_test"
```

Now, this solution requires quite a bit of refactoring, but it has the advantage that it works, it is extensible and it is more flexible and more typesafe than the proposed adapt solution.

Comment: @solyd you create a **typeclass** for each common functionality and you provide the instance for each typeclass for each type that can be implemented. And the cool thing about this is that you do not have to edit any existing class, you can create instances of a typeclass for an external type. You only need to provide the implicits in use site. I would recommend you to read more about the topic. The only code you have to modify _(not add)_ are the functions that use your `As` to be generic and use the **typeclass** instead.

Comment: @solyd 4 lines of code that are slower, more fragile, more rigid and more unsafe. **typeclasses** will give you more control over which can and can't be used, are more flexible since the methods in each class do not have to be named the same and can have different parameters, will be faster in runtime _(but slower at compile time if you make hard use of automatic derivation)_. But, if you prefer your solution go ahead, I just think it was worth showing you how you can use this pattern.

Comment: @solyd ah, you may had say it was for testing before _(if you did sorry for not noticing it)_ I then agree that probably all the machinery would be too much _(for this case, for production code, IMHO the cost is more than reasonable)_. Just to answer, fragile in that you do not have control, maybe for some class you do not want to allow the adaption or maybe it exposes some method you do not want to be exposed. Rigid. In that the methods has to be called the same and have the same parameters with the same types. And unsafe in that reflection by nature is unsafe, you loose all guarantees.